# What does "common refrain" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The common refrain for my entire tenure here: We all get too much email.

https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/04/email-isnt-the-problem.html
Of course I googled separate words and phrases from this sentence, but it still doesn't make any sense.

Refrain means "to stop yourself from doing something that you want to do"

Comment: A full dictionary definition of refrain should have answered this for you. Sometimes a quick search truncates the definition just before the bit you need.

Comment: You had to open the tab on Google, the 2nd meaning was there all along. The answer should have been given as a comment: [***a comment or complaint that is often repeated.***](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=refrain+definition) because  EL&U is not a dictionary service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Refrain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refrain)*** in the sense of:

> - a phrase that is often repeated:
>
>   - *"Every vote counts" is a familiar refrain in politics.*

From:

> - repeated line or number of lines in a poem or song, typically at the end of each verse.

(Cambridge Dictionary)